# Error drawing model in opengl

Tags: opengl, go, glfw

So i'm trying to a basic opengl program that reads in an `.obj` file and then renders it (the obj file contains triangle vertices in the format 
`v 1.000000 2.000000, 3.00000`.

So here's my code to do that (im using GLFW and a Golang binding library for it) (also im currently ignoring normals).

```
gl.Begin(gl.TRIANGLES)
for scanner.Scan() {
    var v0, v1, v2 float32
    t := strings.Split(scanner.Text(), " ")
    line := scanner.Text()
    fmt.Sscanf(line, "v %f %f %f", &v0, &v1, &v2)
    if t[0] == "v" {
        gl.Vertex3f(v0, v1, v2)
    }
}
gl.End()
```

However when I go to run this the result isnt quite right

[image]

I tried it on a few other files I found around the internet and I get similar results. It almost seems like the triangles vertices are offset or something.

Comment: Have you run it through a debugger? Are the values of the vertices the same as the ones in the file?

Answer (score 3):

You should read all vertices data into array. Obj file contains information about triangles, and how vertices should be indexed. Lines starting with `f` contains 3 numbers which describes triangles. So your code should look like this (I don't know go):

```
var vertices [1000*3] float32
for scanner.Scan() {
    var i=0
    var v0, v1, v2 float32
    var vv byte
    t := strings.Split(scanner.Text(), " ")
    line := scanner.Text()
    fmt.Sscanf(line, "%c %f %f %f", &vv, &v0, &v1, &v2)
    if vv == "v" {
        vertices[i] = v0
        vertices[i+1] = v1
        vertices[i+2] = v2
    }
    i = i+3
}
gl.Begin(gl.TRIANGLES)
for scanner.Scan() {
    var v0, v1, v2 int
    var vv byte
    t := strings.Split(scanner.Text(), " ")
    line := scanner.Text()
    fmt.Sscanf(line, "%c %d %d %d", &vv, &v0, &v1, &v2)
    if vv == "f" {
        gl.Vertex3f(vertices[v0], vertices[v1], vertices[v2])
    }
}
gl.End()
```

Answer (score 1):

Obj files store in addition to the vertices (v-lines) also how they have to be combined into faces (f-lines). The vertices themself are stored without a particular ordering, which means that the first triangle is not necessarily composed of the vertices 0-2.

You will have to read all of the vertices into a vector/list/array and then parse the face entries which can be composed (according to here) in four different ways depending on which additional information (normals, texture coordinates) are additionally stored:

```
f v1 v2 v3 ...
f v1/vt1 v2/vt2 v3/vt3 ...
f v1/vt1/vn1 v2/vt2/vn2 v3/vt3/vn3 ....
f v1//vn1 v2//vn2 v3//vn3 ...
```

where

```
v  ... index into the list of v-entries
vt ... index into the list of vt-entries (texture coordinates)
vn ... index into the list of vn-entries (normals)
```

For your example, you will have to do something similar to this pseudocode (assuming that all faces are already triangulated)

```
v-list vertices[];
parse each v-line into v-list

foreach (f-line)
{
    parse v-indices -> {v0, v1, v2}

    draw triangle {vertices[v0], vertices[v1], vertices[v2]}
}
```